# EF Core - why 'infinate' nested eager loading?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a one-to-many relationship between two entities: Maps and MapNodes.  When I eager load MapNodes with Maps (via an Include()), I get Map, and I get related MapNodes, but in the related MapNodes, I also get the full parent Map again.  That Map then has associated MapNodes (again), and so on...

I need to limit the contents of the query to one level (i.e MapNodes) and not have the eager loading go deeper.

```
[Table("maps")]
public partial class Maps
{
    public Maps()
    {
        MapNodes = new HashSet<MapNodes>();
    }

    <...>
    [InverseProperty("Map")]
    public virtual ICollection<MapNodes> MapNodes { get; set; }
}

[Table("map_nodes")]
public partial class MapNodes
{
    public MapNodes()
    {
    }

    <...>
    [Column("map_id", TypeName = "int(10) unsigned")]
    public uint MapId { get; set; }

    public Maps Map { get; set; }

}
```

When I execute the following query:

```
    var map = await context.Maps.Include( x => x.MapNodes).FirstOrDefaultAsync( x => x.Id == id);
```

I get an infinate eager loading:

```
{
    "id": 1063,
    "mapNodes": [
        {
            "id": 25784,
            "mapId": 1063,
            "map": {
                "id": 1063,
                "mapNodes": [
                    {
                        "id": 25784,
                        "mapId": 1063,
                        "map": {
                            "id": 1063,
                            "mapNodes": [
                        ...
```

Comment: This is called `Reference Loop Handling`. It's not available in `System.Text.Json` yet.
but its available in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` In your `startup` you can configure it via `AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson()` and `x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;`.

Comment: Thanks!  Can you post a solution And I'll 'accept' it.

Comment: EF-generated objects will always contain circular reference if you query related entities (with `Include`). It's a better choice to create a set of classes to represent flat data (Response/DTO/ViewModel objects) and to map entity/model objects to those before sending data to the client-side, instead of sending query results directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft replaced `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` in ASP.NET Core 3 with their own implementation which is `System.Text.Json` but it doesn't support `Reference Loop Handling` handling yet.

So in order to configure `Reference Loop Handling` you need to add the nuget package for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` then configure it this way:

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```